# Height causes issue in div tag in ng Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, nginfinitescroll

I am using NIS to make endless scrolling, I implemented and it works fine except one issue. Like I am using `float: left` to maintain the div tag. But after using `float` it sends multiple request at a time, but when I remove `float:left` it sends single request which I want.

I am getting 20 results at a time from server

I don't have public URL to give example on JsFiddle or Plunker.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/lib/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/customjs/endless_scroll.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .test{
      float:left;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller='DemoController'>
      <div id="scroll" infinite-scroll='reddit.nextPage();' 
      infinite-scroll-container="'scroll'"
      infinite-scroll-disabled='reddit.stopscript'   
      infinite-scroll-distance='2'>             

      <div ng-repeat='item in reddit.items'>
           <div class="test">
           <div style="height:30px;width:200px; border-style:solid;border-width:medium;">{{item.bookmark_id}}</div>
          <div style="height:100px;width:200px; border-style:solid;border-width:medium;">{{item.bookmark_title}}</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show='reddit.busy'>Loading data...</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);

myApp.controller('DemoController', function ($scope, Reddit) {
  $scope.reddit = new Reddit();
});

myApp.factory('Reddit', function ($http) {
  var Reddit = function () {
   this.items = [];
   this.busy = false;
   this.stopscript = false;
  };

Reddit.prototype.nextPage = function () {

  if (this.busy){
   return;
  }
 else{
    this.busy = true;

 var url = "http://example.com/get_recent_articles/";   
  $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
    if (data.recently_added.bookmarks.length == 0) {

        this.stopscript = true;
    }
    else {               
        this.items.push.apply(this.items, data.recently_added.bookmarks);             
     }
     this.busy = false;
    }.bind(this));
   }
 }; 
 return Reddit;
});
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

*Thank You.*

Comment: try using `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes When I use `display:inline-block` then all the `Div ` tags display vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you float elements, the parent collapses. I'm assuming your `ng-show` element is the one that triggers the load, so you always want that to sit below the content (so that when you scroll to it, it triggers the content to load). This means you need to use a clearfix on the parent, so that it expands with the floated content, instead of collapsing.

```
#images::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

You can learn more about how floats work here: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Can you clear my doubt, where to put this image attribute?
since I didn't use `images ID` above so far.

Comment: @abarik Try `#scroll`. `#images` is just an example; like my post describes you need to apply it to the parent of the floated elements.

Comment: I got it @Christian Thanks for respond